# How do I force Jenkins 2.107.2 to use java-1.8.0 while launching an agent?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am running into below error while launching an agent on my Jenkins 2.107.2 ,looks like this is a popular error and based on my homework it sounds like need to launch the agent using 1.8,I installed 1.8 and my /usr/lib/jvm folder looks like below,however when I launch the agent it still using java 1.7.0, how do I force Jenkins to launch the agent using 1.8?

**/usr/lib/jvm**

[image]

Error:

```
[05/02/18 10:17:59] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[05/02/18 10:17:59] [SSH] Copying latest slave.jar...
[05/02/18 10:17:59] [SSH] Copied 762,466 bytes.
Expanded the channel window size to 4MB
[05/02/18 10:17:59] [SSH] Starting slave process: cd "/home/username" && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java  -jar slave.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hudson/remoting/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Slave JVM has terminated. Exit code=1
[05/02/18 10:17:59] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[05/02/18 10:17:59] [SSH] Connection closed
```

Comment: Are you able to log onto the node (preferably as the same user that Jenkins is trying to use)? If so, what's the output of: `command -v java; ls -al $(command -v java); echo $JAVA_HOME; java -version`

Comment: @bto - the output is `/usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Sep 26  2016 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-3~12.04-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly set the path to the java executable in the node launch configuration:

1. Click on Manage Jenkins
2. Click on Manage Nodes
3. Click on the node you are trying to launch
4. Click on configure
5. Under **Launch method** there is a button labeled **Advanced...**; click it
6. Find the option **JavaPath** and set it to the full path to the java executable you want to use; like:

   ```
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
   ```
7. Save
8. Relaunch the node

Answer (score 1):

You can set JAVA_HOME environment variable for the node by configuring it.

1. Click on Manage Jenkins
2. Click on Manage Nodes
3. Select the Node on which you are running your build
4. Click on configure.
5. Add environment variable to it (JAVA_HOME)

Comment: I added JAVA_HOME home variable with value `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` ,it still picks `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

Comment: Did you add JAVA_HOME in node properties of slave ?  Also did you restart your slave after setting property ?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, set the path to the Java executable you want to use in the *jenkins-slave.xml* file that gets created in the folder where the jenkins jar file is located.

For example:

```
<service>
  <id>jenkinsslave-C__jenkins</id>
  <name>Jenkins agent (jenkinsslave-C__jenkins)</name>
  <description>This service runs an agent for Jenkins automation server.</description>
  <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe</executable>
```